# How to Understand Autoregressive Process MATLAB Code?

Tags: matlab, autoregressive, spectral-analysis

This is supposed to be a code to calculate the true PSD of a 4th order autoregressive process:

```
a=[2.7607 -3.8106 2.6535 -0.9238];
sigma2=1; % Variance of the errors
for j=1:4
    phase(1:nshp1) = 2.*pi*frq(1:nshp1)*j*delt;
    fphi2(1:nshp1,j) = a(j)*...
        complex(cos(phase(1:nshp1)),sin(-phase(1:nshp1)));
end
fphi = sum(fphi2,2);
fphi=1-fphi;
smfphi=real(fphi).^2+imag(fphi).^2;
sdf4=sigma2*delt./smfphi;
sdf4=10*log10(sdf4);
```

I need to be able to use this and apply it to any data set but I don't understand what the code is doing well enough for that. The biggest thing I am confused about is what the "a" vector is. All my professor would say is that they're the coefficients you need to calculate the true PSD, which doesn't really help at all. I don't understand how you know what those coefficients are supposed to be.

Comment: You does PSD stand for?

Comment: PSD is the Power Spectral Density in spectral analysis. It's the total variance per unit time.